# VS2015 is really slow loading symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Today I've run into a problem where any program I try to debug in VS2015 takes an age to load all the pdb's for my program and other programs (in the order of 20 minutes or more for a simple dx12 sample).  I could skip them but actually I really want them loaded for various reasons.

This isn't a problem with the solution or project as I get the issue debugging standard microsoft samples ie the dx12 samples hosted on github.  I believe all my settings are correct for the symbols settings, here's my settings:

[image: VS2015 Symbol Settings]

I've also already tried emptying my symbols cache and loading them all again.  This takes an age too!  My symbols cache is on an SSD which looks to be working fine. My internet connection is fine 19ms ping, 45Mb down, 18.7Mb up.

One unexpected thing is that the messages say the symbols can't be found:

> 'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32):
>   Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32):
>   Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\D3DCompiler_47.dll'. Cannot find or open
>   the PDB file. 'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'D3D12Fullscreen.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

(that just took 10 mins to get that far btw).  That is really strange as you can see they are all standard dll's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

I'm using this version of VS2015:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.02001
>
> Installed Version: Enterprise
>
> Architecture and Modeling Tools   00322-90150-00888-AA088 Microsoft
>   Architecture and Modeling Tools
>        UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States
>   and other countries.
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-90150-00888-AA088 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-90150-00888-AA088 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-90150-00888-AA088 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   00322-90150-00888-AA088 Windows Phone
>   SDK 8.0 - ENU
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.5.00830.1
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11107.0 ASP.NET and Web
>   Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.8 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.4.4 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition   5.0.0.15294 NVIDIA Nsight Visual
>   Studio Edition provides tools for GPGPU and graphics development. 
>   Copyright © NVIDIA 2010 - 2015. •Direct3D® and DirectX® are registered
>   trademarks of Microsoft Corporation in the United States and/or other
>   countries. •Microsoft Detours is used under the Professional license
>   (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). •Gardens
>   Point Parser Generator Copyright 2005 Queensland University of
>   Technology (QUT). All rights reserved. •NLog Copyright © 2004-2006
>   Jaroslaw Kowalski (jaak@jkowalski.net) •IronPython and WPFToolkit used
>   under Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL) and are Copyright © Microsoft
>   Corporation •Portions of RadControls for WPF © 2010-2011 by Telerik
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved. •zlib and libpng used under the
>   zlib/libpnc license (http://opensource.org/licenses/Zlib)
>
> Warning: This computer program is protected by copyright law and
>   international treaties. Unauthorized reproduction or distribution of
>   this program, or any portion of it, may result in severe civil and
>   criminal penalties, and will be prosecuted to the maximum extent
>   possible under the law.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60519.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   1.8.36.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   14.0.25527.01 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

System info from dxdiag:

> ### ------------------ System Information
>
> ```
>   Time of this report: 9/4/2016, 22:15:11
>          Machine name: REMOVED
>            Machine Id: Unknown
>      Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview 64-bit (10.0, Build 14915) (14915.rs_prerelease.160826-1902)
>              Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
>   System Manufacturer: LENOVO
>          System Model: 20378
>                  BIOS: 9ECN31WW(V1.14)
>             Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.5GHz
>                Memory: 16384MB RAM
>   Available OS Memory: 16296MB RAM
>             Page File: 6018MB used, 13221MB available
>           Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
>       DirectX Version: DirectX 12
>   DX Setup Parameters: Not found
>      User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
>    System DPI Setting: 240 DPI (250 percent)
>       DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
>              Miracast: Available, with HDCP Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported
>        DxDiag Version: 10.00.14915.1000 32bit Unicode
> ```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35a31403-24f5-4552-8e3c-4c65f2b98c17/microsoft-symbol-server-is-slowbroken?forum=windbg

Comment: Your settings say to (try to) download symbols for ALL modules. Is that what you want? Yes, that will take a long time.

Comment: MSDL has been on the fritz since Friday.  It is a holiday weekend in the USA, it isn't going to get fixed until Tuesday at the earliest.  Temporarily untick the option.  Next time don't delete the cache.

Comment: click on the link "specify excluded modules" and add your files to the exclude list

Comment: @Blorgbeard: no downloading symbols shouldn't take over half an hour for a simple DX12 sample.

Comment: Microsoft is aware of the slow symbol server issue, they work on it. this is the answer that I got from a Microsoft contact.

Comment: the issue should be fixed now according to Andy Luhrs (MSFT): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/35a31403-24f5-4552-8e3c-4c65f2b98c17/microsoft-symbol-server-is-slowbroken?forum=windbg#5b8bd19d-3bf8-4cda-a22b-aa9977e72ae2

Comment: is your issue now also fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an issue with the symbol server. Alot of people are having the issue atm.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35a31403-24f5-4552-8e3c-4c65f2b98c17/microsoft-symbol-server-is-slowbroken?forum=windbg

Also if you search "symbol server" on twitter you will see that this is apperently a known issue and that you are not the only one having to deal with this in recent days...

Answer (score -2):

Try disabling IntelliTrace in tools/options in VS2015. I had the same slowness issue and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that already due to another post I saw but that didn't help so I turned it back on.