# Visual Studio Debugging is stuck at "Attaching to the web server"

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-7.5

When I run my Web API application I get the following window:

[image: Attaching to the web server]

It just stays like that indefinantly, until I hit cancel.

When I do hit cancel, this error message is shown:

[image: Catastrophic Failure]

I have tried rebooting, and running `iisreset /restart` but it does not fix it.

**Any ideas what I can do to get my debugger working again?**

NOTE: My Web API 2 project's Servers setting is set to `Local IIS`.  My service is hosted by IIS and when I am not debugging, it works fine.

Comment: I switched to `IIS Express` and it started working.  Then I switched back (after a bit) and that started working.   Weird.

Comment: I did also make some changes to the symbol server setup.  They did not seem effective, but could have contributed to the fix.

Comment: I've got the same issue here, Recycling the application pool helps sometimes. Tried deleting the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folders

I've also got issues loading the symbols but that seems to be a more comon issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321665/vs2015-is-really-slow-loading-symbols

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as I commented before I had this same issue, but I now figured out the cause and have a solution.

I just got a new machine last week (this issue was actually one of the reasons why) and after a while I had the same issues, not being able to debug my projects. Luckily because I was installing all the updates one by one I was able to pin-point when it started happening.

It seems the latest update for the "[Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesEloff.MicrosoftASPNETandWebTools-9689)" extension breaks something.

Sadly, uninstalling or reverting the Web Tools extension is not easy: [Remove this extension by going to the Windows control panel and modifying your Visual Studio installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245041/visual-studio-thinks-microsoft-web-developer-tools-is-installed). I had to remove Visual Studio completely and reinstall it (repair didn't do the trick).
You can update and install all your extensions as you wish, just make sure that you don't update the Web Tools extension

I tested this on my old machine and it did the trick there as well.

I've also created an Issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/912) as I won't be updating the extension until this is fixed, if anybody has additional information please add it to the Issue.

Answer (score 24):

A possible fix:

Check the "Enable Just My Code" in Tools->Options->Debug

Comment: That solved my issue. The idea is Visual Studio was trying to load debugging information for all the IIS .net dlls that were loaded by w3wp.

Comment: Yes this was my issue to. I had been debugging Azure Functions which normally need this turning on and it stopped VS2017 from attaching to IIS

Answer (score 7):

I just did a reset for all the settings for VS and it worked again.

Tools => Import and Export Settings => Reset All Settings

good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue for Visual Studio 2017 and like with the previous post I had Debugging option "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" ticked. Un-ticking fixed the issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for this!

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar issue and found that unchecking the "Enable Source Server support" option under Debugging options worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015, go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging and deselect "Enable .NET Framework source stepping". This may relate to an issue with loading symbols, so if you want to keep the ability to debug .NET Framework source, then it may help to search the web for how to clear the symbol cache, or preload it, or set your symbol server, and so on.

[image: Enable .NET Framework source stepping]

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see this in the current answers, so thought I'd give my 2 cents in 2022:

What worked for me:
Make sure to check that your IIS application pool hasn't been stopped (and restart it if it is), and then if that's not the case, restart your IIS server.

If you don't where those settings are, open our Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager, Application Pools are in the left-hand column, and restart/start/stop your server is in the right column.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, I just restarted my machine and ran the solution, no other windows opened not even a browser, although visual studio took a long time to open (30+ projects in a solution) the problem did not reoccur.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in VS 2017 and un-checking 'Native code' did the trick. Not sure why it was checked.

[image: Native code debugging]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I set Debugging ->Symbols -> To "Load Only Specified Modules" to include the symbols for, in my case a devops symbols feed for some internal NuGet packages

[Options>Debugging>Symbols>Load Only Specified Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGach.png)

By checking the option "Always load symbols where located next to modules" the setting won't mess with the regular/classic debugging in VS for your own code

This way the Symbols are still loading where needed and Visual Studio is not trying to load debugging information for all the IIS .net dlls that were loaded by w3wp

Alternatively it can also be configured to not load symbols for microsoft.*.dll and it will also work.